# Bitcoin SPV not able to fetch transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-core-development, spv

I am developing a Bitcoin wallet SPV and using 3rd party SDK for the same.

However, I tried to create wallet and it gets successfully created and I can also restore those wallets but amount and transactions not coming. Making amount always 0 as amount calculation depends on transactions.

```
//
//  XORWallet.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Paresh Thakor on 06/07/19.
//

import UIKit

let KEY_MNEMONIC = "wallet_mnemonic"

class XORWallet: NSObject {
    static let shared = XORWallet()

    var peerGroup: WSPeerGroup?
    var wallet: WSHDWallet?

    func create(_ seed: WSSeed? = nil) -> WSHDWallet? {
        let parameters: WSParameters = WSParametersForNetworkType(WSNetworkTypeMain)
        var theSeed: WSSeed? = seed
        parameters.scriptAddressVersion()

        if theSeed == nil {
            theSeed =  (WSSeedGenerator.sharedInstance()?.generateRandomSeed())!
        }

        if let s = theSeed {
            let store: WSBlockStore = WSMemoryBlockStore.init(parameters: parameters)
            wallet = WSHDWallet.init(parameters: parameters, seed: s)
            let downloader: WSBlockChainDownloader = WSBlockChainDownloader.init(store: store, wallet: wallet)
//            wallet?.usedAddresses()
            print(wallet?.usedAddresses()!)
            print(wallet?.receiveAddress()!)
            print(wallet?.sortedTransactions())
            print(theSeed?.mnemonic()!)
            let peerGroup: WSPeerGroup = WSPeerGroup.init(parameters: parameters)
            peerGroup.startConnections()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "WSPeerGroupDidStartDownload"), object: nil, queue: nil) {(note) in
                print("Jay Mataji")
            }
            peerGroup.startDownload(with: downloader)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "WSPeerGroupDidFinishDownload"), object: nil, queue: nil){(note) in
                print("Completed")
            }

            self.peerGroup = peerGroup
        }
        return wallet
    }

    func generateSeed() -> WSSeed? {
        let theSeed: WSSeed? = WSSeedGenerator.sharedInstance()?.generateRandomSeed()
        return theSeed
    }

    func saveToUserDefaults() -> Bool {
        if let w =  wallet,
            let m = w.seed()?.mnemonic() {
            let def = UserDefaults.standard
            def.set(m, forKey: KEY_MNEMONIC)
            def.synchronize()

            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    func loadSavedWallet() -> WSHDWallet? {
        let def = UserDefaults.standard
        if let m = def.string(forKey: KEY_MNEMONIC) {
            let seed = WSSeed(mnemonic: m)
            return create(seed)
        }

        return create()
    }
}
```

Create a wallet like,

```
if let wallet = XORWallet.shared.create(XORWallet.shared.generateSeed()) {
            print(wallet.allReceiveAddresses()!)
            print(wallet.balance())
        }
```

Please help me solving the issue as here `wallet.balance()` always comes 0. There is balance for this account.

I am  new to bitcoin dev and may messed up  something.

Comment: Are you rescanning the blockchain once you create your wallet? Or in the case of SPV "replaying" the chain once all your addresses are added to the bloom filter?

Comment: @pinhead  I did not really get you. As  mentioned  in code, I am creating wallet by `create()` and then access balance and address by specific methods. I don't get about bloom filters and "replaying" stuff.